How can the <img> element in HTML access and include an image from a folder on my computer?
I want to know how img in html accesses images stored locally. I'm trying to add an image saved in  pictures folder but the browser is displaying images that are saved on my desktop only. How can I display images stored in other folders?
<img src="pictures/erd.jpg" alt="ERD"/>
Here, the image I want to display is stored in pictures folder but the browser only displays alt text .

Is your html file also on Desktop? Did you try by giving complete path?

The src property accepts a path which is related to the location of the HTML page. The path should be a relative path from the location of the HTML page to the location of the image. So if the page is in the Documents folder and the image is in the Pictures folder, the path might by something like "../Pictures/erd.jpg".
